# Curl works only if the sniffer is enabled - encrypted response content

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to download an internet page using curl c++.
Using http analyzer I can see the header and use it in cURL.
When I execute my GET request by curl I have a crypted response content, something like this:

```html
‹í=ksÛ8’Ÿ“ªùíÞÊ©1%‘Ô3‰=å8NÆ»ñccMfo§æX   IH(BÃ‡mewÿÏÝß¸ûc×
ð%‰’(Kžä®&›ÐÝèn¼^~ûúê´ÿï×gdNÜã§/ñq©7:ªðP;ïWÈýÄõ‚£Ê8§Ïëõ»»»ÚYþ¨®÷z½ú=f¨`FFã§O_NXH‰=¦~ÀÂ£Jµ.|†02öÙp÷†"}êÐë
R¢ðè„UFÌc>
…_!¶ðBæN ÷Ê$ÍZ‡œ^Ü`Ñ9x€åÞ(¬¸‹`ì–P?:Yu‡8t /]î}">s*A8sY0f,¬p6…ì!»ëvTâú@ª0C6™Öm1™ú,„_Ÿ0ÄÍh;–ÑèÒv‡1Çh9tØëtMÖ`FË6›5Àó½Þlµ›ÝN§Õ¨  s8=ªPW½
CîB'L¸WGZ\²?×§>÷BUŽÙ6;³aši9òã>JúÔ‡Ô³gq_ÿøkÄüY-y×ôšYKjj6M½g6Ú)í3æí«²»’º¶;F«­?RI~Èâ‚:Íf·e˜­’l¼8¬ã‡»¡ó%sÙ~A‰Ü¦øßàeuà´Å´¸‘F+ßÝ…æÉ   {‰ž;—Z®qÏrøˆ‡Ô•©”©˜FÓ¤Ë»­V«Û4öGMAãÌDFf’ˆô-&A‡ÆÐÛ9®{asêZˆ3Täò„t½G%$¤ƒs’d‹àé3•T­üšØêšFÓ0¹­ÂPØ L#ásºHâÊ¯   ‰ºÙê5ÌîoH¢±žFc‘Î—Â¥Ô˜¦&
A»¹Ç¾æ[SN=(Å÷ùpê(p¹Ãüú{ˆÈ·œëhàr»~
j³oýY®1GŸÆÎndŽd0îuÑùrD
#Ÿi [äu¿Âî¸çUÐ¡b$¾ª‚´AÀ _
e('Cá   ‹{¶×dE¢9
¨Â¹¡…V‘Ø‡|KFÇv»ÛíöZ_”kœÖz”DKKtB=MÙÅ‰:2ÛF¯Ñx³êY`&FØ¾­–ÙyŒ¢†B
```

If I execute my request when the sniffer is enabled all works correctly.
I can't understand why... The website is in http and not in https.

This is my code:

```html
        curl_easy_reset(curl);

        /*  Headers ed altri parametri validi per ogni cURL*/
        struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Host: www.*****.it");
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0");
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Connection: Keep-Alive");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 90);         

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer); 

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.******.it/"); 
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        writeFile("a.html", readBuffer);
```

What can change the sniffer when it is enabled? 
Why I receive a strange response content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line:

```
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
```

You're saying that you accept `gzip, deflate`, so the server is sending it back compressed. Try removing that line.

Comment: You're right! Thank you. Do you know why if I enable the sniffer it works?

Comment: It'll be something to do with caching or the server tracking clients. Your sniffer presumably doesn't send that `Accept-Encoding` header.